# Список значений с быстрым поиском в Delphi

Tags: delphi

У меня есть большой набор простых числовых значений (1,3,23,32,2,4,10 ...). Всего в наборе около тысячи значений. Мне нужно организовать быструю проверку на наличие ключа в наборе. 
Каждый раз перебирать в массиве тысячу значений не выглядит хорошим решением.
Сейчас использую Dictionary и в value устанавливаю 0. 
Возможно есть более хорошее решение? Что-нибудь наподобие hashset в c#.

Answer (score 2):

массив сортируете (если данные статические - то лучше сразу хранить отсортированный массив) и применяете [бинарный поиск](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA). Код на делфи - http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/binary_int_array_search.html

Сложность поиска - логарифмическая.

В некоторых случаях можно применить радикс поиск. То есть, массив делим на группы (1-9, 10-99, 100-999 или по первой цифре). Каждую с вложенных групп делим также или просто применяем бинарный поиск.

Если скорости бинарного поиска будет недостаточно (ну мало чего), а памяти достаточно, то просто заводим массив булевых значений размером по максимальному элементу. Потом пробегаем по массиву и исходных элементов, и используя их как индексы проставляем true в новосозданном массиве. Теперь поиск будет константный.